# About Facebook App Review terms

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, review

The reason for this question is because I have an application that is in the process of "App Review required by August 1, 2018 to retain access to Facebook Platform APIs"

In this sense, when I want to add permissions (items) to be reviewed, it is required that I specify how I connect to Facebook and how each permissions that I need reviewed is used. In my particular case the question is because the login mode with Facebook is through connection with the Graph Explorer API through a service. Therefore I have no visual way to expose that log. I have a website that displays the data pulled from this service. How would I do in that particular case to demonstrate the logging process?

Comment: Did you ever successfully get your app reviewed?

Comment: Until now I'm still pull information from my apps